Flutter | isolate strange behavior in closures
I understand that isolates in Dart run in separate memory spaces and communicate via message passing and I should serialize these objects first before sending them to the isolate, but I found a strange behavior while using the isolate in a closure, here is my example:
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Closure and Isolate Example')),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            final a = Text("TEXT");

            await Isolate.spawn((_) {
              print(a);
            }, []);
          },
          child: Text('Run Isolate'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

This example worked and printed the widget.
but if I put the object outside the onPressed like this:
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final a = Text("TEXT");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Closure and Isolate Example')),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            await Isolate.spawn((_) {
              print(a);
            }, []);
          },
          child: Text('Run Isolate'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

it throws an error:
`E/flutter (25736):  <- Instance of 'WidgetsFlutterBinding' (from package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart)
E/flutter (25736):  <- field this in SemanticsBinding._handleSemanticsActionEvent (from package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart)
E/flutter (25736):  <- _onSystemFontFamilyChangedZone in Instance of 'PlatformDispatcher' (from dart:ui)
E/flutter (25736):  <- platformDispatcher in Instance of 'FlutterView' (from dart:ui)
...
so I can use any object from the closure in the isolate and it will work, no matter how complex this object is, how this happens?

dart implicitly copies objects you reference within the closure when you spawn another isolate.  There is also a known issue where dart has a tendency to over capture variables, and copy over more than necessary. You can send most types of objects to another isolate, but there are some exceptions listed in the documentation: https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.4.0/dart-isolate/SendPort/send.html
